# Limit of $e^x/x^3$ at infinity without l'Hopital

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I'm looking for a nice proof that $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^x}{x^3} \to +\infty$$
without derivatives (i.e., Taylor or l'Hopital).

My current approach is to change it into a sequence: For any $x$, there exists $n$ such that $n\leq x\leq n+1$. Then
  $$\frac{e^x}{x^3}\geq\frac{e^n}{(n+1)^3}=:a_n.$$
Since
  $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a_n}{a_{n-1}}
  = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{e^n}{(n+1)^3}\frac{n^3}{e^{n-1}}=e>1,$$
we get that
  $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{e^x}{x^3} \geq \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \to +\infty.$$

However, this approach seems quite complicated to me. Is there any elementary proof that were significantly simpler? For instance, do I overlook some trivial bound (i.e., not derived from Taylor) on $e^x$ that could be helpful?

PS: We define $e^x:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (1+x/n)^n$.

PPS: I tried to check whether a question like this exists, but I couldn't find it. If it exists, I apologize.

Comment: How did you define "$e^x$"?

Comment: As $\lim (1+x/n)^n$, I'll include this.

Comment: Would you like it using the definition of limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use $x=3t$ so the limit is
$$
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{e^{3t}}{27t^3}=
\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{1}{27}\left(\frac{e^t}{t}\right)^{\!3}
$$
Thus you see that you just need to show
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{x}=\infty
$$
Now the problem is in how you define $e^x$.

With $e^x=\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+x/n)^n$, the Bernoulli inequality gives
$$
\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^{\!n}\ge 1+x
$$
but this seems to weak. It is not if you consider
$$
\frac{e^x}{x}=\frac{(e^{x/2})^2}{x}\ge
\frac{(1+x/2)^2}{x}
$$

Note that this technique shows that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}{x^\alpha}=\infty
$$
for every $\alpha>0$, just in one swoop: consider $e^x=(e^{x/\alpha})^\alpha$.

Answer (score 12):

There is an "elementary" inequality $e^t \geq t+1$, from which we can deduce $$\frac{e^x}{x^3} = \frac{(e^{x/4})^4}{x^3}  \geq \frac{(\frac{x}{4} + 1)^4}{x^3} \geq \frac{1}{4^4}\frac{x^4}{x^3} = \frac{x}{4^4} \to \infty$$.

Comment: $e^x = e^{4(x/4)}$ is very cute :)

Comment: but your "elementary" inequality comes from the Taylor series expansion of $e^x$ ;)

Comment: @sranthrop Not really, you only need convexity and the value of the derivative at zero.

Comment: I have exactly the problem @sranthrop speaks about. How do you prove that $e^t\geq t+1$ without taking derivatives?

Comment: @Ian How do you prove convexity?

Comment: @yo' Here is one way: $y=\exp(x)$ is the unique solution to $y'=y,y(0)=1$. From this it follows by uniqueness of ODEs that $y$ is monotone, so $y'>0$, but $y''=y'$, so $y''>0$, thus you have convexity. So only two derivatives are required.

Comment: @Ian If you ever write $y'$, you are quite obviously using derivatives.

Comment: @yo' You want *no* derivatives whatsoever (not just no Taylor or L'Hospital)? In that case you can use binomial expansion after proving that the sequence $(1+x/n)^n$ is increasing for $x>0$. This shows $(1+x/n)^n=1+x$ plus more positive terms, so $e^x>(1+x/n)^n>1+x$.

Comment: @Ian Yes, I know. The problem is that this is for 1st year university students, and we tend to disallow using derivatives for limits at the beginning. And after one does what you do, it gets very complicated. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @yo' After doing what, the binomial expansion? You don't need to rigorously deal with all the terms, you just need to realize that they are all positive and explicitly calculate the first two terms. You need *some* way to derive the Bernoulli inequality...

Comment: One can use the Bernoulli inequality (provable for example by a geometric sum) to conclude that $(1+x/n)^n\geq 1+x$ (at least if $|x|<n$, which one can assume since only large $n$ is interesting anyways). Since $n\mapsto (1+x/n)^n$ is increasing, one gets $e^x\geq 1+x$.

Comment: mickep @Ian Oh I now realize the trick (sorry it's early in the morning here). That looks really nice, thanks!

Comment: @yo' It seems I slept through all the discussion here!  If we know some basic facts about $e$, we could also argue that $e^x \geq 2^x \geq x+1$ for $x\geq 1$.  Of course, making this rigorous probably also requires a Bernoulli argument, which seems unavoidable to me without derivatives.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x\gt 0$. Expand $\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ using the binomial theorem. We find that the term in $x^4$ is
$$\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)}{4!n^4}x^4.$$
Note that if $n\ge 6$ then $n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\gt \frac{n^4}{2^3}$.
It follows that $e^x\gt \frac{1}{8\cdot 4!}x^4$, and therefore 
$$\frac{e^x}{x^3}\gt \frac{x}{8\cdot 4!}.$$

Comment: With the Binomial Theorem method,with the usual meaning for $A^x$ when $A>0$, we obtain,for $A>1$ and $k>0$,that $0=\lim_{x\to \infty}  x^k/A^x$ .

Comment: @user254665:  The idea you mention, with the exponent a positive integer, is useful early in an analysis course, before one has defined the general exponential. I used the binomial theorem here because then we only need OP's definition of $\exp(x)$, and none of its "algebraic" properties.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can use the definition of $e^x$.

$e^x$ always has all positive terms in the expansion for positive x.

There is always a term in the definition of $e^x$ of $\frac{x^4}{24}$ and so $e^x > \frac{x^4}{24}$

$$e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{6}+\frac{x^4}{24}+... > \frac{x^4}{24}$$

Above some value of $x$ we must have $x^4 > 24x^3$ and that's $x>24$

So at any value above $x=24$ we are guaranteed

$$\frac{e^x}{x^3} > x$$

And the limit of that as $x$ approaches $\infty$ is $\infty$